# RegEx for "fixing" e-mail headers, making them a single line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do unfolding RFC 822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227783/how-to-do-unfolding-rfc-822)
>   [Parsing e-mail-like headers (similar to RFC822)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804880/parsing-e-mail-like-headers-similar-to-rfc822)

I have some input data that is similar to e-mail data, in that long lines are wrapped to the next line.  For example:

```
robot-useragent: ABCdatos BotLink/1.0.2 (test links)
robot-language: basic
robot-description: This robot is used to verify availability of the ABCdatos
                   directory entries (http://www.abcdatos.com), checking
                   HTTP HEAD. Robot runs twice a week. Under HTTP 5xx
                   error responses or unable to connect, it repeats
                   verification some hours later, verifiying if that was a
                   temporary situation.
```

The `robot-description` field is "too long" for one line, and is wrapped to the next.  For aid in parsing this data, I would like to come up with a RegEx that can be used with `preg_replace()` to replace with the following conditions:

- New line characters followed by whitespace
- **Not** replacing new line characters followed by additional new line characters

Example output:

```
robot-description: This robot is used to verify availability of the ABCdatos directory entries (http://www.abcdatos.com), checking HTTP HEAD. Robot runs twice a week. Under HTTP 5xx error responses or unable to connect, it repeats verification some hours later, verifiying if that was a temporary situation.
```

I am new to RegEx.  How can I build such an expression?  If you choose to answer, please include a brief explanation of the components in the expression.  I'd really like to learn how to do these.

I've started with this:  `\n([^\S])*`  It is close.  http://codepad.org/iMObpgFX

Comment: @MarcB, This isn't a duplicate.  In my other question, I am asking about how to handle the headers as a whole in manner similar to the built-in IMAP functions.  In this question, I am specifically asking about RegEx to re-join the lines.  In my view, these are entirely separate questions.  While they relate to the same goal for me, I would like to know a solution for both.  If you disagree, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try:

`(\r|\n)\s+`

```
(\r|\n) # matches both newline and carriage return 
\s+     # any whitespace (tabs, spaces, new lines)
```

[Try it](http://regexr.com?32dhf)!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, this seems to put everything all on one line.  http://codepad.org/zGRAzqhM

Comment: Boris, I see that it is working in your example.  Any idea why the codepad version isn't?  Are there some additional options that I need to specify?

Comment: It is working too on codepad, check out the source or use `nl2br()` (The new line are not interpreted in HTML)

Comment: Codepad shows the raw output with line numbers, not HTML.  You can see this example with your expression, with a new line and test text after it:  http://codepad.org/zfWgK80b

Comment: @Brad, I suspect there is something wrong with codepad. I tested both on my local env and on http://ideone.com/d4WMT and the result is what it is expected to be. Note that your answer is doing exactly the same (except it doesn't allow new line as whitespace). `[ \t\n]` = `\s`